# Python pivot column with comma and bracket separated

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I am working with a large dataframe that currently looks like this:

| ID | Region | Noun |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | North America | [('Everything', 'NP'), ('the product','NP'), ('it','NP')] |
| 2 | North America | [('beautiful product','NP')] |

The third column contains noun phrase(s) and each phrases have labels (two capital letters).
All of these are in quotation marks and then coupled in brackets, and then put in square brackets which make it difficult for me to separate and pivot.

I would like to pivot the last column **only**, so the final output will look like this:

| ID | Region | Noun | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | North America | everything | NP |
| 1 | North America | the product | NP |
| 1 | North America | it | NP |
| 2 | North America | beautiful product | NP |

The annoying part is that some rows have more brackets than others.
Is there any way I could make this happen on Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have strings in column `Noun`. You can apply [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) on them to convert them to Python lists:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

# apply if Noun are strings, skip otherwise
df["Noun"] = df["Noun"].apply(literal_eval)

df = df.explode("Noun")
df[["Noun", "Type"]] = df["Noun"].apply(pd.Series)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   ID         Region               Noun Type
0   1  North America         Everything   NP
0   1  North America        the product   NP
0   1  North America                 it   NP
1   2  North America  beautiful product   NP
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```
df2 = df.explode('Noun').reset_index(drop=True)
df2[['ID','Region']].join(pd.DataFrame(df2['Noun'].tolist(),columns = ['Noun','Type']))
```

Output:

```
   ID         Region               Noun Type
0   1  North America         Everything   NP
1   1  North America        the product   NP
2   1  North America                 it   NP
3   2  North America  beautiful product   NP
```